# Is this procedure a Simple Random Sample?

Tags: statistics, sampling

Page 62 Question 3 of Sampling: Design and Analysis

> Each of the 10,000 shelves in a certain library is 300 cm long. To estimate how many
>   books in the library need rebinding, a librarian takes a sample of 50 books using the
>   following procedure: He first generates a random integer between 1 and 10,000 to
>   select a shelf, and then generates a random number between 0 and 300 to select a
>   location on that shelf. Thus, the pair of random numbers (2531, 25.4) would tell the
>   librarian to include the book that is above the location 25.4 cm from the left end of
>   shelf number 2531 in the sample. Does this procedure generate an SRS of the books
>   in the library?

My thoughts:

In order to be an SRS, every unit in population has the same probability of being in the sample of size n. As a result, I believe that this method would in fact generate an SRS, as each book has the same probability of being selected.

Is this correct to assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thicker books have a higher probability to be sampled than thinner books, so the method would not generate an SRS unless all books have the same thickness, which is not likely to be the case.

Comment: Wow, didn't even think of that... Makes complete sense